# TransactionScope what happens when i neither commit and nor Rollback and create another Transaction

Tags: c#, transactionscope

Am going through a weird issue which am trying to address using Transaction scope

```
 foreach(..) {
  callFunc();
 }

 function callFunc() {
  using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
   try {
    /* Perform transactional(Insert) work here on Table A*/

    if (somecondition) {
     return;
    }

    scope.Complete();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    scope.Dispose();
   }
  }
 }
```

On my first call to callFunc() inside TransactionScope while performing insert on table A i keep a break point and execute select from table A wont produce result until the transaction is complete

lets say in my first call am returning without committing or rollback and when the second time this function is called i dont notice transaction scope working

and am not able to figure out why ?

Even if i have not commited my transaction once i go out of scope it automatically rolls back is my assumption but why is my second time call to transactionscope is not working.

I see records in my table even before transactions is committed. Any clarity on understanding this will be much appreciated.

Difference i note is

First time Scope --> CommitableTransaction --> PromoterType has some guid

second time Scope --> CommitableTransaction --> PromoterType  empty guid

**Update**

Even i Commit or Dispose Transaction on return am seeing the same issue

Thanks

Comment: Can you show more code, please?

Comment: @Mike these transactions have lot of inline old queries which part of code you are looking for ?